# Standard boiler wiring

Tags: relay, home-automation

My oil powered boiler's controller is terrible and commercial replacements are expensive.

So, I'm going to make my own.

Looking at the back of the existing controller, there's this wiring diagram which seems as though the controller just switches power with a relay to one of two terminals (for each of hot water and central heating).

[image: Wiring Diagram]

I'm just wondering what purpose putting power to pins 1 and 2 will have? What are they likely connecting to?

Comment: how is it wired right now? ... please provide a wiring diagram that shows the boiler ... also provide a link to the controller manual

Comment: That's inside the wall mate, I couldn't tell you, as I didn't install it... As for the controller, it's a Drayton LP522 https://manualzz.com/doc/23544322/drayton-lp522-programmer-manual